# Capturing a value in a select and using it in an object at the top level with jq

Tags: amazon-web-services, jq, aws-cli

Given the response from `aws ec2 describe-subnets`, which looks like this:

```
{
    "Subnets": [
        {
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-2b",
            "AvailabilityZoneId": "usw2-az2",
            "AvailableIpAddressCount": 8187,
            "CidrBlock": "10.0.96.0/19",
            "DefaultForAz": false,
            "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": false,
            "State": "available",
            "SubnetId": "subnet-08000000000000000",
            "VpcId": "vpc-06ba0000000000000",
            "OwnerId": "350000000000",
            "AssignIpv6AddressOnCreation": false,
            "Ipv6CidrBlockAssociationSet": [],
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "aws:cloudformation:logical-id",
                    "Value": "PrivateSubnet02"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "aws:cloudformation:stack-name",
                    "Value": "dev"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "Private Subnet2"
                }
            ],
            "SubnetArn": "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:350000000000:subnet/subnet-08000000000000000"
        }
    ],
    "NextToken": "eyJOZXh0VG9r=="
}
```

I'd like to produce a JSON object that contains the value of the `Name` tag, along with the subnet ID, if the name matches some string (e.g. testing).  This was my initial attempt:

```
aws ec2 describe-subnets | jq '
.Subnets[] 
| select(
    .Tags[]? 
    | select(.Key == "Name") 
    | .Value as $name 
    | .Value 
    | test("testing")) 
| {"Name": $name, "SubnetId": .SubnetId}'
```

Which results in the error message:

```
jq: error: name/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 9:
| {"Name": $name, "SubnetId": .SubnetId}           
jq: 1 compile error
```

The following works, so I know the problem is limited to accessing the $name variable outside the select statement:

```
aws ec2 describe-subnets | jq '
.Subnets[]
| select(
    .Tags[]? 
    | select(.Key == "Name") 
    | .Value as $name 
    | .Value 
    | test("testing")) 
| {"SubnetId": .SubnetId}'
```

The problem is that I am attempting to use the $name variable when it is out of scope, but I don't know how to define the `$name` var ahead of time.

What is the best way of capturing the value of the `Name` tag (we happen to know there is only one instance of it, and if there wasn't, it would be fine to do something like 1. picking the first instance, 2. picking the last instance, or 3. erroring).

Answer (score 3):

I've found a solution that works:

```
aws ec2 describe-subnets | jq '
.Subnets[]
| select(
    .Tags[]?
    | select(.Key == "Name")
    | .Value
    | test("testing"))
| . as $obj
| .Tags[]
| select(.Key == "Name")
| .Value as $name
| {"Name": $name, "SubnetId": $obj.SubnetId}'
```

Which returns:

```
{
  "Name": "testing-vpc-stack-Subnet02",
  "SubnetId": "subnet-02000000000000000"
}
{
  "Name": "testing-vpc-stack-Subnet01",
  "SubnetId": "subnet-06900000000000000"
}
{
  "Name": "testing-vpc-stack-Subnet03",
  "SubnetId": "subnet-09b00000000000000"
}
```

But I'm curious if there are other options.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
jq  '.Subnets[]|
    { "Name": ( .Tags|from_entries| .Name), "SubnetID": .SubnetID} |
    select(.Name | test("testing"))'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below command which does not use `JQ` for parsing, totally base on aws-cli query

```
aws ec2 describe-subnets --query 'Subnets[*].{Subnet_ID:SubnetId,Name:Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value|[0]}'  --output json
```

Output of the query

```
    {
        "Subnet_ID": "subnet-abcd",
        "Name": "Staging-2a"
    }
```

Comment: Yes, there is rarely a need to use JQ. The AWS CLI `--query` parameter uses [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html) and is _very_ powerful. See: [Controlling command output from the AWS CLI - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes exactly but I think one reason that people go for JQ might be its documentation as AWS documentation provide basic usage of such command.